# Dynamic module does not define module export function(PyInit_example)

Tags: python, c, windows, swig

I was recently building a **C extension** for **python using swig**.

At first, I ran :

`swig -python example.i`

Then it generated `example.py` & `example_wrap.c`

After I ran:

`gcc -c example.c example_wrap.c -I D:/path_to_python/Python/include`

Ok, then it generated objects  `example.o & example_wrap.o`

After I want to make a shared object file and ran :

`gcc -o example.dll -s -shared example.o -Wl,--subsystem,windows`

It generated `example.dll`.
I renamed the extension of `example.dll` to `example.pyd`.Then copied and pasted `example.pyd` & `example.py` to `Python\DLLs` & `Python\Lib` folders respectively.

Till everything went good.
But when I open `python.exe` and write `import example` and an error occurs. It says:

`Dynamic module does not define module export function(PyInit_example)`.

I tried various things but not work. I want to generate `.pyd` from `.dll`.

I used :

-Windows 10

-Python310

-GCC MinGW 64

I appreciate those who help.

Comment: the final name should be `_example.pyd` (with underscore).  You `import example` which loads `example.py`, which then does `import _example`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The final name should be `_example.pyd` (with underscore).  You `import example` which loads the generated `example.py`, which then does `import _example` and loads `_example.pyd`.  No need to copy anything into the Python subdirectories.

Make sure the `example.i` file starts with `%module example`.

I don't have MingGW installed but here's a command line build using VS2019:

example.i

```c
%module example

%inline %{
int add(int a, int b) {
    return a + b;
}
%}
```

Demo below.  Note `/Fe` names the output file, and `/LD` creates a DLL.

```
C:\demo>swig -python example.i

C:\demo>cl /LD /Fe_example.pyd /Ic:\python38\include example_wrap.c -link -libpath:c:\python38\libs
Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.29.30136 for x64
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

example_wrap.c
Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 14.29.30136.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

/dll
/implib:_example.lib
/out:_example.pyd
-libpath:c:\python38\libs
example_wrap.obj
   Creating library _example.lib and object _example.exp

C:\demo>py
Python 3.8.10 (tags/v3.8.10:3d8993a, May  3 2021, 11:48:03) [MSC v.1928 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import example
>>> example.add(5,6)
11
```

Here's my best guess with MingGW (untested, since I don't have it installed):

```
swig -python example.i
gcc -c -fpic example.c example_wrap.c -Ipython3.9
gcc -shared example.o example_wrap.o -o _example.pyd
```

Comment: Does renaming directly of example.dll to example.pyd will work?

Comment: @Chetan I normally use a compiler switch to name the final result, but no reason a direct rename won't work.

Comment: @Chetan Your linking step must include `example_wrap.o` as  well.  Was `add_basic.o` a typo?

Comment: So what should I do then?  I want it to run like other standard python modules not by using ctypes.CDLL().

Comment: @Chetan `ctypes` has nothing to do with swig.  Once you have `example.py` and `_example.pyd` in the same directory as your script, just `import example`.

Comment: How to convert .dll to .pyd then?

Comment: @Chetan A .pyd *is* a .dll, just renamed.

Comment: @Mark_Tolonen , i used `gcc -o _example.pyd -s -shared example.o -Wl,--subsystem,windows
` but again it says `dynamic module does not define module export function (PyInit__example)
`. I also used `gcc -shared example.o example_wrap.o -o _example.pyd` but return undefined references.  helpme!

Comment: @Chetan You have to compile example_wrap.c and link to example_wrap.o.  See my edit for my best guess with gcc, based on the [swig docs](http://www.swig.org/Doc4.0/SWIGDocumentation.html#Introduction_nn8).

Comment: @Mark_Tolonel do you have any command for that